# Catch connection error in WebService::Solr Perl module

Tags: perl, solr

I can't work out why Solr keeps crashing. I've written a shell script that will auto reboot it:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(tomcat7 nginx mysql);

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "Checking $i"
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $i | wc -l) > 0 ))
    then
    echo "$i is running!!!"
    else
    echo "service $i start\n"
    service $i start
    fi
done

# re-run, but this time do a restart if its still not going!
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "Checking $i"
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $i | wc -l) > 0 ))
    then
    echo "$i is running!!!"
    else
    service $i restart
    fi
done
```

However, even that doesn't seem to work. I just had to manually restart it again, because it has been offline for the last 3 days (only happened to notice, as I was checking the error logs)

The dropouts are much less than before (maybe once every couple of weeks). I would however, like to be notified when they occur.

I'm using this Perl module: http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WebService-Solr-0.23/lib/WebService/Solr.pm to do the work (yes, I'm aware its pretty limited, but it does what I need)

My old code was just:

```
            $solr = WebService::Solr->new( SOLR )
```

However, when the Solr has gone offline, you get a nasty error message:

> Could not parse JSON response: malformed JSON string, neither tag,
>   array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before
>   "Can't connect to loc...") at
>   /srv/www/site.net/www/cgi-bin/admin/WebService/Solr/Response.pm line
>   42. Can't connect to localhost:8080

I was trying to use `eval {}` to catch the error, but even that doesn't seem to work:

```
        my $solr;
        eval {
            $solr = WebService::Solr->new( SOLR )
        };

         if (@$) {
            print $IN->header;
            print "FOO: @$";
            exit;
         }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can catch these errors? (I'm then going to make it email me, so that I know the problem has happened!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's not `WebService::Solr->new()` that casts the exception, but `$response->content`, which is called implicitly from `$response->docs`.

You should move your `eval` to that part of your code:

```
my $response = $solr->search( $query );
eval {
    for my $doc ( $response->docs ) {
        print $doc->value_for( $id );
    }
};

if ($@) {
    print "FOO: $@ \n\n";
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. I was also trying to just `eval {}` the search - but in fact the `eval` needed to be wrapped around the **WHOLE** part of the code. Thanks again!